# Check if numeric value contains only one kind of digit

Tags: sas

Is there an elegant way to check in SAS Base if a numeric value is made of only one kind of digit?

Example:

```
1       -> Yes
11      -> Yes
111     -> Yes
1111    -> Yes
1121    -> No
9999999 -> Yes
9999990 -> No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to share an additional solution with regex:

```
data have;
input x;
datalines;
1
11
12
111
1111
1121
99999999
9999990
;
run;

data want;
set have;
if PRXMATCH("/\b1+\b|\b2+\b|\b3+\b|\b4+\b|\b5+\b|\b6+\b|\b7+\b|\b8+\b|\b9+\b|\b0+\b/",x);
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something like this.

Realize that SAS does not store leading 0s in numbers, so the last one in your example will pass -- that 0 will not show up.

This converts the numbers to strings and then compares the individual characters in the string.  Alter the format in the put statement as needed.

Also note that a decimal will fail because `.` will be compared to the numbers.  If you need these to pass, then remove the `.` from the string.

```
data have;
input x;
datalines;
1
11
12
111
1111
1121
99999999
09999999
1.11
;
run;

data test;
set have;
pass = 1;
format temp $32.;
temp = strip(put(x,best32.));
do i=1 to length(temp)-1;
    pass = pass and (substr(temp,i,1) = substr(temp,i+1,1));
    if ^pass then leave;
end;
drop temp i;
run;
```

Comment: You can get around the decimal error by converting decimals to spaces and compressing: temp = compress(tranwrd(strip(put(x,best32.)), ".", ""));

Comment: @TechnoCore, that one will properly fail in the above code.  If this answers your question, please accept the answer.